# Find incoming call's IMSI

Tags: mobile-phones, sim-card

I am trying to find out if there is a way to detect the IMSI # of a phone that is calling you.  So say for example, caller A calls person B- person B wants to know A's imsi #.  I thought I read this information is transmitted to the MSC- is there a way to ask the MSC for that information?

Comment: Is this really programming related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IMSI number (International Mobile Subscriber Identity) is a unique number that is private.

It is not sent to other phones, a randomly generated TMSI is sent instead.

This is because the IMSI number could be used in forging SIM cards and eavesdropping on phone calls. **It is not possible to obtain the IMSI by any normal procedures and doing so would be illegal.**

Comment: Thanks.  I'm working on a research project this summer to detect spoofed caller ID, and I thought if I was able to get the IMSI of the incoming call, and then use that to look up the number associated with that IMSI #, then compare the displayed caller ID number with the number associated with the IMSI number I'd be moving forward with the project.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible then since the IMSI is not sent to other phones and the TMSI is random (and probably only to obtain with surveillance/wiretapping devices). You can however get your own sim card's IMSI though it would not be of any use.

You could research security weaknesses of intercepting GSM communications between a phone (your phone to make it legal) and the GSM tower, since there are articles on that it might also be a lot easier.

Comment: That sounds like it could be a promising topic for the fall!

Comment: You *can* get the IMSI of a calling party if you have the right HLR interconnection agreement. This isn't illegal. If the person has spoofed the cLI then there is a good chance that they might have spoofed it to a CLI which does not exist, in which case a normal "HLR lookup service" can tell you the number does not exist. If you do find a HLR service who will give you the IMSI then this is extra information, however you would have no way of knowing still if the calling party's real IMSI matches the one you have looked up against the MSISDN.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% agree with previous answer.
Yes, it is impossible to obtain IMSI of the phone calling you. Pairs IMSI - MSISDN (phone number) pair are stored in the HLR.

But it **isn't illegal** to obtain IMSI by normal procedures. If you have physical access to the card you can just read EF IMSI. It isn't protected at all. Probably prev. author mentioned that it would be illegal to obtain IMSI of remote phone. If so, yes, it would be illegal because you'll need to have an access to MNO's servers.